# Ejecutable en netbeans muestra pantalla "Browse JavaFX Application classes"

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

Quiero realizar un ejecutable de mi sistema hecho en el IDE NetBeans, pero me sale esta ventana con el mensaje "Browse JavaFX Application classes", alguien me podría ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Quiero realizar un ejecutable, pero al momento de realizar el deployment me sale esta ventana, y no puedo depurar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al crear una aplicación `JavaFX`, ademàs de tener una clase que tenga el mètodo `main(String[] args)` **debes crear una clase que extienda de la clase `Application` de JavaFX**, si no se tiene definida se mostrarà la pantalla que expones en tu pregunta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al tener una clase que extienda de `Application` tu aplicaciòn se mostrarà sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]